# TextBox value to Slider.Value

Tags: c#

Binding slider to textbox:

```
textbox.Text = Slider1.Value.ToString();
```

But how to bind textbox to slider?

Comment: `Slider1.Value = double.Parse(textbox.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Building off @Dmitry try something like this:

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      // Convert the text to a Double and assign to slider
      double value;
      if (double.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value))
      {
         Slider1.Value = value;

         // If the number is valid, display it in Black.
         textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      }
      else
      {
         // If the number is invalid, display it in Red.
         textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      // If there is an error, display the text using the system colors.
      textBox.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
   }
}
```

and don't forget to wire up this event code to the TextChanged event.

```
textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `WPF`, then you can create a property on your controller:

```
    private int _Text;
    public int Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._Text != value)
            {
                this._Text = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
```

and then bind both the `Slider` and the `TextBox` like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Text}" />
<Slider Value={Binding Text}" />
```

Make sure your controller is your DataContext... on your `xaml.cs` file set it:

```
Controller = new MyController();
this.DataContext = Controller;
```